# Skrollr enable after clicking button

Tags: skrollr

I am currently making a website that uses Skrollr and there is one thing that i cant't get done. I want my website to load at the bottom. There is a registration form with a normal scroll and only after you click the submit button it is possible to go up through the content of the website and see the Skrollr effects. What is the best way of doing this with skrollr?

Comment: Two pages and sessions? Or is this not an option?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have only one page.

You'll have to have an ajax call that will output the markup of your web page as you dont want people to be able to see the markup in dev tools unless they registered. (don't ask me how to in this thread as this is not related to skrollr). I can recommend the following what I found to be the most logical solution.

You simply create a class in your js to handle skrollr library states (destroy(), init(), ect) and then after your ajax markup has been loaded or display:static; css has been applied within your submit button event listener you simply run your init().